running gulp project throws library not found
im trying to run a node.js project which have gulp configuration, when running npm build error is thrown that gulp-imagemin library is not found, below is the error stack trace and Dockerfile
error stack:
[6/6] RUN npm run build:
0.566
0.566 > thub@1.0.0 build
0.566 > gulp
0.566
1.389 [08:34:46] Using gulpfile /usr/src/gulpfile.js
1.390 [08:34:46] Starting 'default'...
1.392 [08:34:46] Starting 'cleanAll'...
1.400 [08:34:46] Finished 'cleanAll' after 8.05 ms
1.400 [08:34:46] Starting 'htmlTask'...
1.401 [08:34:46] Starting 'cssTask'...
1.401 [08:34:46] Starting 'scssTask'...
1.401 [08:34:46] Starting 'jsTask'...
1.402 [08:34:46] Starting 'jsPluginsTask'...
1.402 [08:34:46] Starting 'imgTask'...
1.403 [08:34:46] Starting 'phpTask'...
1.483 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "gifsicle"
1.494 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "optipng"
2.005 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "gifsicle"
2.005 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "optipng"
2.071 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "gifsicle"
2.071 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "optipng"
2.087 [08:34:46] Finished 'jsTask' after 686 ms
2.088 [08:34:46] Finished 'phpTask' after 685 ms
2.128 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "gifsicle"
2.128 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "optipng"
2.171 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "gifsicle"
2.171 [08:34:46] gulp-imagemin: Couldn't load default plugin "optipng"
2.209 [08:34:46] 'imgTask' errored after 807 ms
2.209 [08:34:46] Error in plugin "gulp-imagemin"
2.209 Message:
2.209     spawn /usr/src/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
2.209 Details:
2.209     errno: -2
2.209     code: ENOENT
2.209     syscall: spawn /usr/src/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
2.209     path: /usr/src/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
2.209     spawnargs:
2.209     stdout:
2.209     stderr:
2.209     failed: true
2.209     signal: null
2.209     cmd: /usr/src/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
2.209     timedOut: false
2.209     killed: false
2.209     fileName: /usr/src/src/images/bg/1.jpg
2.209     domainEmitter: [object Object]
2.209     domainThrown: false
2.209
2.209 [08:34:46] 'default' errored after 820 ms
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |     RUN npm install
  15 |
  16 | >>> RUN npm run build
  17 |
  18 |     EXPOSE 3000
--------------------

Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine

# Install Chromium
RUN apk add --no-cache chromium

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

WORKDIR /usr/src

# Copy app source
COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]


package.json
{
"main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp",
    "prod": "gulp prod"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.1",
    "cssnano": "^6.0.0",
    "del": "6.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-pretty-html": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-purgecss": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.60.0"
  }
}

i tried to build docker image and also deploy in cloud run, im getting the above error gulp-imagemin library is not found

Which platform are you running this on? My educated guess/crystal ball is telling me you might be on arm64 and are building an arm64 Docker image, and the mozjpeg package that's been published 2 years ago might only be shipping an amd64 cjpeg. If you're on an ARM CPU, try adding --platform=linux/amd64 to the docker build command.

https://github.com/imagemin/mozjpeg-bin/issues/47#issuecomment-699629892 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880883/using-imagemin-mozjpeg-with-docker-throws-this-error-spawn-unknown-system-error
